# Unity - How to enable setter injection in configuration file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, unity-container, setter

I've created a [controller factory](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt2-controllers.html) and registered my types in code. I can do the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public MasterEntities DbContext { get { return Container.Resolve<MasterEntities>(); } 
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //DbContext can be used here properly...
    }
}
```

However I would like to have the property injected in the setter instead of having to call `Container.Resolve<TypeName>()` explicitly. Preferrable without using attributes or some configuration in code...

```
public MasterEntities DbContext { get; set; }
```

**How can this be configured in my `.config` file? Or does this require the use of attributes or configuration in code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<register type="HomeController">
  <property name="DbContext" />
</register>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I understand, but can this be done "generically" from the perspective of `DbContext`. So that every controller that i create afterwards automatically has `DbContext` injected if it has that property?

Comment: No, properties are configured based on the concrete type.